# Contract creation code storage out of gas in mainnet

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm trying to deploy a contract on the mainnet, but I get the error "contract creation code storage out of gas", tried with gas 3_000_000, 30_0000_000, 300_000_000, but the error is the same. Here is a link to the code of this contract only in the test network https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7d9db3a612f77eb59a3ea7f0fbb3d997c58402ff#code

Please advise which way to go, because this is not the first time this error appears, but all the last times, after a certain time the deploy was done.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have the transaction hash of a failed deployment? It was deployed at testing so it should deployable to main. I'd start looking at the constructor, perhaps some of the deploy parameters is wrong.